# Java Implement an interface type method in implement interface

Tags: java, interface, reference-type

There is an interface called Range like

```
public interface Range {
    public Range newRange(int from,int to);
    public boolean isIn(int value);
    public int min();
    public int max();
    public Range add(Range r);
}
```

In the implement interface, the `Range newRange(1,5)` is to set a range number from 1 to 5, and the method `Range add(Range r.newRange(6,8))` adds the range from 1 to 5 plus 6 to 8 based on the method `Range newRange(1,5)`.  `boolean isIn(int value)` return if the value is in this range.`int min()` return the minimum value in the range.  How can I implement the methods using class as a reference type? By passing an object? My `newRange` is

```
public Range newRange(int from,int to){
    RangeImplem impIns = new RangeImplem();
    impIns.from = from;
    impIns.to = to;
    return impIns;
}
```

I have no idea on this question and a little confusing on the class as reference type. Thanks.

Comment: To implement it, you don't need. To use it, you need to..

Comment: `newRange` should not be a method of the interface. That is (usually) the constructor of the class implementing the `Range` interface. In your case, that would be the `RangeImplem` class.

Answer (score 0):

I think your interface is incorrect.
You call it Range, but inside it can hold multiple ranges.

So for good solution add methods to the Range to get multiple ranges.

Or here some workarounds:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class RangeImpl implements Range {

    private class SimpleRange {
        public SimpleRange(int from, int to) {
            this.from = from;
            this.to = to;
        }
        final int from;
        final int to;

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

            SimpleRange that = (SimpleRange) o;

            if (from != that.from) return false;
            return to == that.to;

        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            int result = from;
            result = 31 * result + to;
            return result;
        }
    }

    private Set<SimpleRange> ranges=new HashSet<>();

    @Override
    public Range add(int from, int to) {
        ranges.add(new SimpleRange(from, to));
        return this;
    }


    @Override
    public int min() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int max() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Range add(Range r) {
        //1) first way If there is only 1 your implementation of Range.
        //extract ranges from inside
        if (ranges instanceof RangeImpl) {
            RangeImpl ri= (RangeImpl) r;
            ranges.addAll(ri.ranges);
        }
        return this;
    }



//    way2:
@Override
public boolean isIn(int value) {
    for (Range externalRange : externalRanges) {
        externalRange.isIn()
    }

    for (SimpleRange range : ranges) {
        range isin
    }
    return false;
}


    @Override
    Set<Range> externalRanges=new HashSet<>();
     //cache supplied ranges and use them in ither methods
    public Range add(Range r) {
        externalRanges.add(r);
        return this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is your answer:

package com.genpact.java.interf;

public interface Range {

    /**
    * Create a new Range object representing an integer interval starting from 'from' and 'to', both limits inclusive
    */
    public Range newRange(int from,int to);

    /**
    * Return if 'value' is in the range defined by this object
    */
    public boolean isIn(int value);

    /**
    * Return the minimum value in range
    */
    public int min();

    /**
    * Return the maximum value in range
    */
    public int max();

    /**
    * Add range 'r' to this range, and return 'this'.
    * 'r' and this may denote disjoint ranges, for instance:
    *  r.newRange(1,5).add(r.newRange(8,10)) denotes a range
    * including 1,2,3,4,5,8,9,10

    */
    public Range add(Range r);


}

package com.genpact.java.impl;

import com.genpact.java.interf.Range;

public class RangeImplem implements Range {

    private int from;
    private int to;

    public RangeImplem() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public RangeImplem(int from, int to) {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }

    @Override
    public Range newRange(int from, int to) {
        Range range=new RangeImplem(from, to);
        return range;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isIn(int value) {
        //Return if 'value' is in the range defined by this object
        if(value >= this.from && value <= this.to){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int min() {
        return this.from;
    }

    @Override
    public int max() {
        return this.to;
    }

    @Override
    public Range add(Range r) {
        this.from = r.min();
        this.to = r.min();
        return newRange(this.from,this.to);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RangeImplem r=new RangeImplem();
        System.out.println(r.newRange(1,5).isIn(3)); //=> returns true
        System.out.println(r.newRange(1,5).isIn(6)); //=> returns false
        System.out.println(r.newRange(1,5).add(r.newRange(8,10)).isIn(6)); //=> returns false

    }
}
```